# JVM error when compiling Kotlin function with coroutines scopes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to migrate my MVP application from Rx to Kotlin's coroutines (which I'm new to).

As I was running some trials, I found that any code with the following structure fails to compile with `org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated`

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
fun a(i: Int) {
    scope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val b = i + 1
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that trying to access the parameter `i` inside the `withContext` is the problem. If I assign the value of `i` to something else inside the function block and use that instead, it works alright. But I have the feeling I might be doing something extra wrong here hehe

This lives in a Presenter. My idea is to use "launch" with the IO dispatcher to call the repository and get some data from the database, then use it to update the UI in the Main dispatcher. It looks solid to me, but I'm a bit worried because apparently no one else is running into that same issue, which might mean this pattern I'm trying to implement should be avoided for some reason.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I found that the problem was with my kotlin plugin version.

I changed it from `1.3.50` to `1.3.72` and... magic :D